# How to remove values from Firebase when item is selected in recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

My app is displaying user's classes in a recylerview. When a user selects a specific class, it opens up another activity that displays the details and there is a button where a user can remove the class. When that button is clicked, i want the id of the class that is saved under the user's list of classes to be removed. I also want the user's uid to be removed from the list of students under the class.Also, I accidentally saved my class id as variable name uid, which shouldn't be confused with the user's uid.Let me know if you have any questions!
Here is my database structure:

```
   {
  "Classes" : {
"-LiGRe3e1YF_HFrHKMgi" : {
  "Students" : {
    "-LiId4URjJ8SWLAP4f4i" : "UhTQgJ4jugMqFtEZK8CsIkTqQl22",
    "-LiIeT5t1T7JpcUee_MJ" : "UhTQgJ4jugMqFtEZK8CsIkTqQl22"
  },
  "class_info" : {
    "date_clasname" : "mm",
    "room_number" : "jjhh",
    "subject" : "Science",
    "teacher" : "mm",
    "uid" : "-LiGRe3e1YF_HFrHKMgi"
  }
 }
},
 "Users" : {
"UhTQgJ4jugMqFtEZK8CsIkTqQl22" : {
  "Classes" : {
    "-LiIeT5slTjC0B3lEqNJ" : "-LiGRe3e1YF_HFrHKMgi"
    "-LiIeT5slTjC0B3lEqNJ" : "-LiGRe3e1YF_HFrHKMgi"
  },
  "User_info" : {
    "email" : "samuelford48@gmail.com",
    "grade" : "12",
    "name" : "Samuel"
      }
     }
   }
 }
```

Here is the code of my activity that shows the classes and gets the data from Firebase:

```
public class home_fragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
private Button button;
//DatabaseReference dref;
//ListView listview2;
//ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
private FirebaseDatabase database;
private DatabaseReference myRef;
private List<Listdata> list;
private RecyclerView recyclerview;
public home_fragment() {

}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);
    //FirebaseUser fbUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    //if(fbUser == null) { Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), LoginActivity.class);
    // startActivity(intent);}

    button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
    recyclerview = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rview);
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = database.getReference("Users")
            .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Classes");
    myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            list = new ArrayList<>();
            final adapter_user_remove_class recycler = new adapter_user_remove_class(list);
          //  final RecyclerviewAdapter2 recycler = new RecyclerviewAdapter2(list);
//String postkey2 = dataSnapshot.getKey();

            String class_id = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

            myRef = database.getReference("Classes").child(class_id).child("class_info");
            // StringBuffer stringbuffer = new StringBuffer();
            myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) 
{

                        Class_model new_class = dataSnapshot.getValue(Class_model.class);
                        assert new_class != null;
                        String nameofclass = new_class.getDate_clasname();
                        String teacherofclass = new_class.getTeacher();
                        String roomnumberofclass = new_class.getRoom_number();
                        String class_key = new_class.getUid();
                        Listdata listdata = new Listdata(nameofclass, teacherofclass, roomnumberofclass, class_key);
                        //String name = userdetails.getName();
                        //String email = userdetails.getEmail();
                        //String address = userdetails.getAddress();
                        listdata.setDate_class(nameofclass);
                        listdata.setTeacher(teacherofclass);
                        listdata.setRnumber(roomnumberofclass);
                   // recycler.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        list.add(listdata);
                    recycler.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        //recycler.notifyDataSetChanged();// Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,""+name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }


                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                    alertDialog.setMessage("Check your connection! If, problem persists please email svhsdev@vigoschools.org!");
                    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                    alertDialog.show();
                }

            });


            RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
            recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutmanager);
            recyclerview.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            recyclerview.setAdapter(recycler);

        }
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
}

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext()).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Check your connection! If, problem persists please email svhsdev@vigoschools.org!");
            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            alertDialog.show();
        }

    });
    return view;
}
```

Here is the code for my recycler adapter:

```
public class adapter_user_remove_class extends RecyclerView.Adapter<adapter_user_remove_class.MyHolder>{

List<Listdata> listdata;

public adapter_user_remove_class(List<Listdata> listdata) {
    this.listdata = listdata;
}

@Override
public adapter_user_remove_class.MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_class_model,parent,false);

    adapter_user_remove_class.MyHolder myHolder = new adapter_user_remove_class.MyHolder(view);
    return myHolder;
}


public void onBindViewHolder(adapter_user_remove_class.MyHolder holder, final int position) {

    final Listdata data = listdata.get(position);
    holder.vdate_class.setText(data.getDate_class());
    holder.vteacher.setText(data.getTeacher());
    holder.vrnumber.setText(data.getRnumber());
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick( final View view) {
            Context context = view.getContext();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, user_remove_class.class);
            intent.putExtra("date_class", listdata.get(position).getDate_class());
             intent.putExtra("teacher", listdata.get(position).getTeacher());
             intent.putExtra("room_number", listdata.get(position).getRnumber());
            intent.putExtra("post_key", listdata.get(position).getUid());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listdata.size();
}


class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView vdate_class , vteacher,vrnumber;

    public MyHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        vdate_class = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_class_name);
        vteacher = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.teacher);
        vrnumber = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.room_number);

    }
  }

}
```

Here is the code for the activity that shows the details and handles the removal of data from Firebase:

```
public class user_remove_class extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button remove_class;
private FirebaseDatabase database;
private DatabaseReference myRef, myRef2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_remove_class);
    final String date_class2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("date_class");
    final String teacher = getIntent().getStringExtra("teacher");
    final String room_number = getIntent().getStringExtra("room_number");
    final String post_key = getIntent().getStringExtra("post_key");
    TextView display_class_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date_tv);
    display_class_name.setText(date_class2);
    TextView display_teacher = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.teacher_tv);
    display_teacher.setText(teacher);
    TextView display_room_number = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rn_tv);
    display_room_number.setText(room_number);
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = database.getReference("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Classes");

    remove_class = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_class_2);
  //  final Query query = myRef.orderByChild("classes").equalTo(post_key);
    //System.out.println(query);
    remove_class.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            myRef = database.getReference("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Classes");
        }
    });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove it by :

```
  remove_class.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                myRef = database.getReference("Users").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Classes").child(post_key);
myRef.removeValue();
            }
        });
```

You can Retrieve the Random key by this method .

```
MyRef.orderByChild("email").equalTo("blabla@blabla.com").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.d("User key", child.getKey());
            Log.d("User ref", child.getRef().toString());
            Log.d("User val", child.getValue().toString());
        }
    }
```

Note that you have to pass the email by putExtra method and then match it with `equalTo();` method . If email is exits in the random key it will retrive the ramdom key simple . :)

Hope it will work. If it works don't forget to Accept the question.

Comment: My database is at the beginning of my question. That does not work because my child is not postkey. I have child "Classes" and then another child that is a random generated key and then the value AT that child is postkey. I just need ti figure out how to retrieve the random generated key and remove the value that is equal to the postkey. Thanks and let me know if you have any more questions!